# Elasticsearch retrieves data from bad the index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I do not know why elasticsearch does not set the appropriate values for the index, and type. He needs to retrieve data from the index = auctions and type = auctions like this is in Model:

**AuctionIndex.java:**

```
@Document(indexName = "auctions", type = "auctions")
public class AuctionIndex {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Long cat;
    private Long tcat;
    private String curr;
    private Long price;
    private Long start_date;
    private Long end_date;
    private String title;
    private String pow;
    private String woj;
    private String loc;
    private String cat_name;
    private Long catdec;
    private Long uid;
    private Long qty;
    ...getters and setters...
}
```

This code works when downloading data as follows:

```
public Map searchByIndexParams(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        Map response = new HashMap();
        NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = this.getSearchQuery(searchParams, pageable).build();
        final FacetedPage<AuctionIndex> search = auctionIndexRepository.search(searchQuery);

        List<AuctionIndex> content = search.getContent();

        response.put("content", content.stream().map(row -> {
            return Auction.builder()
                    .cat(row.getCat())
                    .item(Long.parseLong(row.getId()))
                    .endts(row.getEnd_date())
                    .startts(row.getStart_date())
                    .loc(row.getLoc())
                    .pow(row.getPow())
                    .woj(row.getWoj())
                    .price(row.getPrice())
                    .qty(row.getQty())
                    .title(row.getTitle())
                    .user(row.getUid())
                    .catName(row.getCat_name())
                    .build();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        response.put("first", search.isFirst());
        response.put("last", search.isLast());
        response.put("number", search.getNumber());
        response.put("numberOfElements", search.getNumberOfElements());
        response.put("size", search.getSize());
        response.put("sort", search.getSort());
        response.put("totalElements", search.getTotalElements());
        response.put("totalPages", search.getTotalPages());

        return response;
    }
```

By downloading all the records in this way:

```
public Map findAllByIndexParams(AuctionIndexSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        List rows = new ArrayList();
        Map response = new HashMap();

        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCurrency()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("curr", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTreeCategoryId()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tcat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("uid", v))));

        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        //access for many uids
        if (searchParams.getUids() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getItemId() != null || searchParams.getTitle() != null) {
                Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUids().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                    filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("uid", v)));
                });
            } else {
                for (String user : searchParams.getUids().split(",")) {
                    boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(user).field("uid"));
                }
            }
        }
        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCategories() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCategories().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }
        if (searchParams.getItemId() != null) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getItemId()).field("_id"));
        }
        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }
        if (searchParams.getLoc() != null) {
            filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("loc", searchParams.getLoc())));
//            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getLoc()).field("loc"));
        }
        if (searchParams.getPow() != null) {
            filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("pow", searchParams.getPow())));
//            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getPow()).field("pow"));
        }
        if (searchParams.getWoj() != null) {
            filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("woj", searchParams.getWoj())));
//            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getWoj()).field("woj"));
        }
        if (searchParams.getCatdec() != null) {
            boolQueryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery(String.valueOf(searchParams.getCatdec())).field("catdec"));
        }
        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getStartDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("start_date").from(searchParams.getStartDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getStartDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getEndDateTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("end_date").from(searchParams.getEndDateFrom()).to(searchParams.getEndDateTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);

        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        if (searchParams.getOrderBy() != null && searchParams.getOrderDir() != null) {
            if (searchParams.getOrderDir().toLowerCase().equals("asc")) {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.ASC));
            } else {
                searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort(searchParams.getOrderBy()).order(SortOrder.DESC));
            }
        }

        String scrollId = searchTemplate.scan(searchQuery.build(), 100000, false);


        System.out.println(scrollId);
        Page<AuctionIndex> page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 500000, AuctionIndex.class);
        System.out.println(page.getTotalElements());
        if (page.hasContent()) {
            while (true) {
                for (AuctionIndex hit : page.getContent()) {
                    Auction row = Auction.builder()
                            .cat(hit.getCat())
                            .item(Long.parseLong(hit.getId()))
                            .endts(hit.getEnd_date())
                            .startts(hit.getStart_date())
                            .loc(hit.getLoc())
                            .pow(hit.getPow())
                            .woj(hit.getWoj())
                            .price(hit.getPrice())
                            .qty(hit.getQty())
                            .title(hit.getTitle())
                            .user(hit.getUid())
                            .catName(hit.getCat_name())
                            .build();
                    rows.add(row);
                }
                page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 500000, AuctionIndex.class);
                if (page.hasContent() == false) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        response.put("content", rows);
        return response;
    }
```

**AuctionService.java:**

```
private AuctionRepository auctionRepository;
    private AuctionIndexRepository auctionIndexRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuctionService(AuctionRepository auctionRepository, AuctionIndexRepository auctionIndexRepository) {
        this.auctionRepository = auctionRepository;
        this.auctionIndexRepository = auctionIndexRepository;
    }
    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate searchTemplate;
```

**AuctionIndexRepository.java:**

```
public interface AuctionIndexRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<AuctionIndex, Integer> {

}
```

**AuctionRepository.java:**

```
@Repository
public class AuctionRepository {

    private final AerospikeClient aerospikeClient;

    @Autowired
    public AuctionRepository(AerospikeClient aerospikeClient) {
        this.aerospikeClient = aerospikeClient;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param auctionId
     * @param transactionIndexId
     * @return
     */
    public Map findTransactionAuctionById(Long auctionId, String transactionIndexId) {
        final Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_ALLEK);
        stmt.setSetName(SET_U);

        final Map<String, Object> aMap = findAuctionUserInSetA(auctionId);
        final Key uKey = new Key(NAMESPACE_ALLEK, SET_U, aMap.get("u") + "_" + aMap.get("p"));
        final Object uRecord = aerospikeClient.execute(null, uKey, NAMESPACE_ALLEK, FUN_FIND_U_ITEM, Value.get(auctionId));

        return parseTransactionAuction((HashMap) uRecord, auctionId, transactionIndexId);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param r
     * @return
     */
    private Map parseTransactionAuction(HashMap r, Long auctionId, String transactionIndexId) {
        return parseTransactionAuction(new Record(r, 0, 0), auctionId, transactionIndexId);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param r rekord z aerospike
     * @return
     * @return
     */
    private Map parseTransactionAuction(Record r, Long auctionId, String transactionIndexId) {
        Map response = new HashMap();
        final Object recordTrans = r.getValue("t");
        final ArrayList<HashMap> trans = Optional.ofNullable(recordTrans).isPresent() ? (ArrayList<HashMap>) recordTrans : new ArrayList<>();
        Object qty = 0;
        Object price = 0;
        for (HashMap hit : trans) {
            if (transactionIndexId.equals(auctionId + "_" + hit.get("buyer") + "_" + hit.get("ts"))) {
                qty = hit.get("qty");
                price = hit.get("price");
                break;
            }
        }

        response.put("qty", qty);
        response.put("price", price);
        response.put("startts", r.getLong("startts"));
        response.put("endts", r.getLong("endts"));
        response.put("qty_auction", r.getLong("qty"));
        return response;
    }

    public AuctionRaw findAuctionRawById(Long auctionId) {
        final Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_ALLEK);
        stmt.setSetName(SET_U);

        final Map<String, Object> aMap = findAuctionUserInSetA(auctionId);
        final Key uKey = new Key(NAMESPACE_ALLEK, SET_U, aMap.get("u") + "_" + aMap.get("p"));
        final Object uRecord = aerospikeClient.execute(null, uKey, NAMESPACE_ALLEK, FUN_FIND_U_ITEM, Value.get(auctionId));

        return parseAuctionRaw((HashMap) uRecord);
    }

    private AuctionRaw parseAuctionRaw(HashMap r) {
        return parseAuctionRaw(new Record(r, 0, 0));
    }

    private AuctionRaw parseAuctionRaw(Record r) {
        return AuctionRaw.builder()
                .cat(r.getLong("cat"))
                .len(r.getInt("len"))
                .start(r.getLong("start"))
                .build();
    }

    public Auction findAuctionById(Long auctionId) {
        final Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_ALLEK);
        stmt.setSetName(SET_U);

        final Map<String, Object> aMap = findAuctionUserInSetA(auctionId);
        final Key uKey = new Key(NAMESPACE_ALLEK, SET_U, aMap.get("u") + "_" + aMap.get("p"));
        final Object uRecord = aerospikeClient.execute(null, uKey, NAMESPACE_ALLEK, FUN_FIND_U_ITEM, Value.get(auctionId));
        return parseAuction((HashMap) uRecord);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> findAuctionUserInSetA(Long auctionId) {
        final Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_ALLEK);
        stmt.setSetName(SET_U);

        final Key aKey = new Key(NAMESPACE_ALLEK, SET_A, Value.get(auctionId / 1024));
        final Map<String, Object> aMap = (Map<String, Object>) aerospikeClient.execute(null, aKey, NAMESPACE_ALLEK, FUN_FIND_A_ITEM, Value.get(auctionId));
        return aMap;
    }

    public List<Auction> findAuctionByUserId(Long userId) {
        final Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(NAMESPACE_ALLEK);
        stmt.setSetName(SET_U);
        stmt.setFilters(Filter.equal("u", userId));

        final RecordSet records = aerospikeClient.query(null, stmt);
        return StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), true)
                .flatMap(l -> {
                    final ArrayList<HashMap> auctionsFromRecord = (ArrayList<HashMap>) l.record.getValue("v");
                    return Optional.ofNullable(auctionsFromRecord).isPresent() ? auctionsFromRecord.stream() : Stream.<HashMap>empty();
                })
                .map(r -> parseAuction(r))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Auction parseAuction(HashMap r) {
        return parseAuction(new Record(r, 0, 0));
    }

    private Auction parseAuction(Record r) {
//        final Object recordTrans = r.getValue("t");
//        final ArrayList<HashMap> trans = Optional.ofNullable(recordTrans).isPresent() ? (ArrayList<HashMap>) recordTrans : new ArrayList<>();
//        final List<Transaction> transactions = trans.stream()
//                .map(m -> {
//                    HashMap recordComment = (HashMap) m.get("c");
//                    Comment comment = null;
//                    if (recordComment != null && recordComment.size() > 0) {
//                        comment = Comment.builder()
//                                .id((Long) recordComment.get("id"))
//                                .ts((Long) recordComment.get("ts"))
//                                .text((String) recordComment.get("text"))
//                                .type((Long) recordComment.get("type"))
//                                .build();
//                    }
//                    return Transaction.builder()
//                            .ts((Long) m.get("ts"))
//                            .qty((Long) m.get("qty"))
//                            .price((Long) m.get("price"))
//                            .c(comment)
//                            .buyer((Long) m.get("buyer"))
//                            .build();
//                })
//                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return Auction.builder()
                .item(r.getLong("item"))
                .startts(r.getLong("startts"))
                .endts(r.getLong("endts"))
                .user(r.getLong("user"))
                .qty(r.getLong("qty"))
                .price(r.getLong("price"))
                .title(r.getString("title"))
                .cat(r.getLong("cat"))
                //                .tcat(r.getLong("tcat"))
                //                .curr(r.getString("curr"))
                .loc(r.getString("loc"))
                .woj(r.getString("woj"))
                .pow(r.getString("pow"))
                .catName(r.getString("cat_name"))
                //                .t(transactions)
                //                .len(r.getInt("len"))
                //                .detSt(r.getLong("det_st"))
                //                .detLen(r.getLong("det_len"))
                //                .start(r.getLong("start"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I do not know why but scroll retrieves the data from the old the index = allek and type = auctions.

How do I know that the old index? And so the result in the old Index is equal to 16k (there is just more data and there are other fields than in the new Index) while in the new Index is the records of about 400.

My question is why is this happening? What I should change to be able to use the scrollbar configuration index = auctions and type = auctions?

I ask you for help I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: How does your `auctionIndexRepository` declaration look like?

Comment: Loook edit AuctionIndexRepository.java

Comment: So any idea what is going on ?

Comment: One more question, what is `AuctionRepository` and what do you use it for?

Comment: Look up I added this class

Comment: @Val did you find something what makes the bad work?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the old index `allek`?

Comment: With the index allek at the moment the application uses for production. For develop using this new index auctions.

Comment: You're developing on the same cluster as where your production application runs?

Comment: Yes I dev on the same cluster